# Amount of possibilities of numbers where each following number is less than the previous number or 0 (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

I have an encoding problem. Given n numbers and k slots. Such that for each slot it can be either 0, or a number less than the previous number.

E.g.

for n=4,k=4

```
0000, 3000, 3200, 3210 etc.
```

for n=7,k=3

```
000, 700, 541, 731, 540 etc.
```

Could anyone please tell me what the pattern here is?

Comment: You could split this into two cases: One where the first digit is $0$ and one where it's not $0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Hint: Consider the difference between consequtive digits. Is there a condition for the sum of the differences?

Comment: Is $731$ allowed?  Or when you say "less than" do you mean "one less than"?

Comment: @saulspatz yes 731 is allowed

Comment: yes i tried @MattiP. , that $$n \choose k$$+1 then the sum seems to depend on n, but im not sure how this will generalize to higher cases

Answer (score 0):

An admissible word is a $j$-element subset of $[n]$, listed decreasing, followed by $k-j$ zeros, whereby $0\leq j\leq k$. It follows that there are
$$\sum_{j=0}^k{n\choose j}$$
admissible entries.