# Given n numbers and k slots. Such that for each slot it can be either 0, or a number less than the previous number, Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I have an encoding problem. Given n numbers and k slots. Such that for each slot it can be either 0, or a number less than the previous number. 
E.g.

for n=4,k=4

```
0000, 3000, 3200, 3210 etc.
```

for n=7,k=3

```
000, 700, 541, 731, 540 etc.
```

Could anyone please tell me what the pattern here is, in other words, what is the formula that describes the number of possibilities?

Some python code that illustrates the problem (the code itself is not important, I'm looking for a closed-form of make_encod(n,k))

```
from math import factorial
import math

def make_encod(n,k):
    tol=[""]
    for i in range(0,k):
        tol=make_strin_from_tile(0,max(n-i,1),tol)
    print(tol)
    return len(tol)



def make_strin_from_tile(f,t,all):
    a=[]
    for b in all:
        for i in range(f,t):
            if len(b)==0 or int(b[-1])>i or int(b[-1])==0==i:
                a.append(f"{b}{i}")
    return a
#just some examples
print(make_encod(3,1))
print(make_encod(3,2))
print(make_encod(3,3))
print(make_encod(5,4))
```

Would output:

```
> 3
['0', '1', '2']
4
['00', '10', '20', '21']
4
['000', '100', '200', '210']
16
['0000', '1000', '2000', '2100', '3000', '3100', '3200', '3210', '4000', '4100', '4200', '4210', '4300', '4310', '4320', '4321']
```

I am looking for a formula that tells me the answer for make_encod(n,k))? There must be something smarter then actually going through this

Comment: Are you the same person who posted this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541230/amount-of-possibilities-of-numbers-where-each-following-number-is-less-than-the#comment7282440_3541230

Comment: @MattiP. yes sry, my accounts are somehow wierd, now i can't log back into the other one. Delete the other one if someone can, sry

Comment: Is 771 allowed for n=3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:
$$P(n,k)=\sum_{z=\max(0,k-n)}^{k} \binom{n}{k-z} $$
Let's call $P(n,k,z)$ the function that gives the number of possibilities with $z$ zeroes in the end. Clearly $z \leq k$. Moreover $z \geq k-n$ (this condition is meaningful if $k-n \geq 0$), otherwise $k-z>n$ and the number of non-null slots can't be bigger than the number of ciphers that we can use to fill them(since we can't do repetitions). Clearly:

$$P(n,k,z)= \binom{n}{k-z}$$

In fact we simply have to choose $k-z$ numbers $\{1,...,n\}$ (the order doesn't matter, because the decreasing order is unique). And clearly:

$$P(n,k)= \sum_{z=\max(0,k-n)}^{k} P(n,k,z)$$

$$P(n,k)=\sum_{z=\max(0,k-n)}^{k} \binom{n}{k-z} $$